# How to run while True in asyncio python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using `asyncio/aiohttp` to send asynchronous `GET` request to different websites.The plan is to fetch 100 urls from a redis queue and send a `GET` request to them asynchronously. Then fetch another 100 urls and repeat the process. Also, if a url fails (timeout or HTTP_status == 403), the process will add it to the end of queue. I've written a code to achieve this but it freezes after sometime. Can anyone tell me how to achieve it ? Here's my code:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import async_timeout
import aiohttp
import aiosocks
import redis
import json

url_list = []


async def fetch(url, session,r_server):
    agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
    headers = {'user-Agent': agent,'accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8','accept':'text/javascript, application/javascript,
     application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br','x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'}
    with async_timeout.timeout(100):
        async with session.get(url,headers=headers) as response:
            status = response.status
            # Store status code somewhere
            ...


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session,r_server):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        try:
            await fetch(url, session,r_server)
        except Exception as e:
            print ("In semaphore",e,url)
            # Push url in redis queue
            ...

async def run(url_list,r_server):
    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for url in url_list:
            # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url, session,r_server))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

async def get_url_list(r_server):
        url_list = []
        # Get url list from redis: queue_list
        for docs in queue_list:
            doc = json.loads(docs.decode("utf-8"))
            url = doc["url"]
            url_list.append(url)


        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(url_list,r_server))
        loop.run_until_complete(future)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r_server = redis.Redis("localhost")
    while True:
      get_url_list(r_server)
      time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You function waits for 3 argumetns `def run(url_list,headers,r_server):` but you give it only 2 `asyncio.ensure_future(run(url_list,r_server))`

Comment: Thanks for correcting . Edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to help you until you've found the point where your script is freezing.
But using synchronous redis client and running event loop over and over is anti-pattern.

Answer (score -1):

> **Ouestion**: 
>   How to run while True in asyncio python?

Replace

```
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

with

```
loop.run_forever(future)
```

Comment: You can not `run_forever()` a future. `run_forever()` does not take arguments.